Can sacrificing a Queen be considered a brilliant move?
Knowing that a brilliant move is only given out by sacrificing a piece, is there any position or past game that had given out a brilliant move via Queen sacrifice?

Levy Rozman has a video "7 BEST Queen Sacrifices In Chess History!" which you may be interested in.

Queen sacrifice brilliancies are very common. What makes you think they might not be considered brilliant?

I was just wondering, because I have made many Queen sacrifices that let to a mate in 1 or 2, but none of them have been brilliant.

Ftacnik vs Cvitan. The reason I started playing KID

@JonahHodge : maybe if the move is not immediately obvious at a first casual glance, it has a higher chance to be seen as brilliant?

Yes, if by brilliant you mean how Chess.com annotates the move.
Some examples from GM Hikaru Nakamura,[1, 2] though there are many more both from him and from other players.
Example 1:
17...Qh3 ends the game due to (18. gxh3 Nxh3#).
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2021.02.24"]
[Round "?"]
[White "DanielNaroditsky"]
[Black "Hikaru"]
[Result "0-1"]
[ECO "C70"]
[WhiteElo "2973"]
[BlackElo "3195"]
[TimeControl "180"]
[EndTime "12:38:23 PST"]
[Termination "Hikaru won by resignation"]
[StartPly "34"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 g6 5. c3 b5 6. Bc2 Bg7 7. d4 exd4 8. cxd4
d5 9. exd5 Nce7 10. O-O Nf6 11. Nc3 O-O 12. Ne5 Nexd5 13. Bg5 Bb7 14. Ne4 h6 15.
Bh4 Qc8 16. Nc5 Nf4 17. Bg3 Qh3 $3 {[%c_effect
h3;square;h3;type;Brilliant;persistent;true] Danya cannot avoid mate on g2,
thanks to 18.gxh3 Nxh3#} 0-1

Example 2:
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2021.06.30"]
[Round "?"]
[White "GMSrinath"]
[Black "Hikaru"]
[Result "0-1"]
[ECO "A06"]
[WhiteElo "2803"]
[BlackElo "3174"]
[TimeControl "180"]
[EndTime "11:57:50 PDT"]
[Termination "Hikaru won by checkmate"]
[StartPly "66"]

1. Nf3 d5 2. b3 c5 3. Bb2 f6 4. e3 e5 5. d4 cxd4 6. exd4 e4 7. Nfd2 f5 8. c4 Nf6
9. Nc3 Be6 10. Be2 Bb4 11. O-O Bxc3 12. Bxc3 O-O 13. Re1 Nc6 14. c5 f4 15. b4 f3
16. Bxf3 exf3 17. Rxe6 fxg2 18. Qe2 Qd7 19. b5 Nd8 20. Re7 Qh3 21. Qe3 Qh5 22.
Qg3 Nf7 23. Rae1 Qh6 24. Rxb7 Ng5 25. Ree7 Nh5 26. Qg4 Rf4 27. Qd7 Nf6 28. Rxg7+
Kh8 29. Qc7 Nh3+ 30. Kxg2 Rxf2+ 31. Kh1 Nf4 32. Nf3 Rxf3 33. Rg1 {White's king
loses an escape square, and the game is over.} 33... Qxh2+ $3 {[%c_effect
h2;square;h2;type;Brilliant;persistent;true]} 34. Kxh2 Rh3# 0-1

Example 3:
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2020.10.13"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Hikaru"]
[Black "LiamVrolijk"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "A06"]
[WhiteElo "3213"]
[BlackElo "2836"]
[TimeControl "180+1"]
[EndTime "10:36:25 PDT"]
[Termination "Hikaru won by checkmate"]
[StartPly "63"]

1. Nf3 d5 2. b3 Bf5 3. g3 e6 4. Nh4 Bg4 5. h3 Bh5 6. Bb2 Nd7 7. d3 Ngf6 8. g4
Bg6 9. Nd2 Bd6 10. e3 Qe7 11. a3 e5 12. Bg2 c6 13. Qe2 O-O-O 14. b4 Rhe8 15. c4
Kb8 16. Nb3 e4 17. Nxg6 hxg6 18. c5 Bc7 19. d4 g5 20. a4 Nf8 21. b5 Ng6 22. bxc6
bxc6 23. Qa6 Nh4 24. Bf1 Nf3+ 25. Kd1 Qd7 26. Bc3 Ka8 27. Kc2 Rb8 28. Be2 Rb7
29. Rhb1 Reb8 30. Bb5 cxb5 31. c6 Rb6 32. Qxa7+ $3 {[%c_effect
a7;square;a7;type;Brilliant;persistent;true]} 32... Kxa7 33. axb5+ Ra6 34. Rxa6#
1-0

Example 4:
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2021.02.01"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Hikaru"]
[Black "ChessLover0108"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "B23"]
[WhiteElo "3184"]
[BlackElo "2832"]
[TimeControl "180"]
[EndTime "18:52:54 PST"]
[Termination "Hikaru won by resignation"]
[StartPly "71"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nc3 d6 3. f4 g6 4. Nf3 Bg7 5. Bc4 Nc6 6. Bb5 Bd7 7. Bxc6 Bxc6 8. d3
Nf6 9. O-O O-O 10. Qe1 b5 11. f5 b4 12. Ne2 Nxe4 13. dxe4 Bxe4 14. fxg6 Bxg6 15.
Nf4 Bxc2 16. Nh5 Bh8 17. Bh6 Re8 18. Nh4 Bg6 19. Qg3 d5 20. Nf5 Bxb2 21. Rae1
Kh8 22. Bc1 Bc3 23. Re3 Bxh5 24. Rxc3 Rg8 25. Qh4 bxc3 26. Qxh5 f6 27. Nh6 Rg7
28. Nf7+ Rxf7 29. Qxf7 Qd6 30. Bf4 Qd7 31. Bh6 Rg8 32. Rxf6 Qg4 33. Rf2 c2 34.
h3 Qd1+ 35. Kh2 c1=Q {The queen is attacked by the bishop, of course, but there
is much better than the difficult endgame that would be ahead after 36.Bxc1.}
36. Qxg8+ $3 {[%c_effect g8;square;g8;type;Brilliant;persistent;true] Mate after
36...Kxg8 37.Rf8#} 1-0
   



[1] Hikaru Nakamura's Most Brilliant Moves On Chess.com, Article version
[2] Hikaru Nakamura's Most Brilliant Moves On Chess.com, YouTube version

This is one of my favourite games of all time
[FEN ""]
[Event "Bundesliga 1997/98"]
[Site "GER"]
[Date "1997.??.??"]
[EventDate "?"]
[Round "2"]
[Result "0-1"]
[White "Lubomir Ftacnik"]
[Black "Ognjen Cvitan"]
[ECO "E97"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[PlyCount "52"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. Nf3 g6 3. c4 Bg7 4. Nc3 O-O 5. e4 d6 6. Be2 e5
7. O-O Nc6 8. d5 Ne7 9. Nd2 Ne8 10. b4 f5 11. c5 Nf6 12. f3 f4
13. Nc4 g5 14. a4 Ng6 15. Ba3 Rf7 16. b5 dxc5 17. Bxc5 h5
18. a5 g4 19. b6 g3 20. Kh1 Nh7 21. d6 Qh4 22. Bg1 Bh3
23. bxc7 Bxg2+ $3 {[%c_effect g2;square;g2;type;Brilliant;persistent;true] 24. Kxg2 Qh3+ $3 {[%c_effect h3;square;h3;type;Brilliant;persistent;true] 25. Kxh3 Ng5+ 26. Kg2 Nh4+ 0-1


(+1) This is a very beautiful conclusion.  Black's Queen sacrifice (24...Qh3+) is only made possible by the preceding Bishop sacrifice (23...Bxg2+) which White should have refused.

I don't understand why this game ends when it does. There are some moves available.

@Wookie did you mean why the moves Kh1 and g2# are not shown? maybe white resigned

I see now and I enjoyed watching this game too : )

@SecretAgentMan - The specific move you're referring to as a "Bishop sacrifice" (Bxg2+) cannot be refused, as there is no other move available to White. The real sacrifice is Bh3, which White did refuse. And I believe that was a mistake. If White accepts the sacrifice (with gxh3), then it's not clear to me how Black forces mate. Black may well win the game in any case, but everything I've tried has White lasting longer by accepting.

@JohnY This was a typo due to being distracted.  Clearly the White King cannot remain in check after 23...Bxg2+; you are correct.   I repeat that this is a very beautiful conclusion.
